# Loop through Json in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have json that I get from an API that returns a value like this

```
[{
    "Location": "/xxx/005D2"
}, {
    "Location": "/xxx/020D2"
}, {
    "Location": "/xxx/061D2"
}, {
    "Location": "/xxx/086D2"
}, {
    "Location": "/xxx/100D2"
}]
```

When I call the URL and access the variable

```
$installs= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $installLocation -Method Get;
```

I get the following

```
Location
--------------
/xxx/100D2
/xxx/120D2
/xxx/110D2
etc
```

How can I loop through these so I only access 1 location at a time?

Comment: `$installs | foreach { $_.location; };`

Answer (score 2):

You acutally don't want to loop through JSON, but through a PowerShell object (`$installs`). You can do that, as with any other PowerShell object.

```
$installs | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Location
}
```